# WPF TreeView Clear Selection

Tags: .net, wpf, treeview

How would I clear the TreeView selection within a WPF TreeView?  I have tried looping through the `TreeNodes` and clearing the `IsSelected` property, however that is a `ReadOnly` property. Any ideas?

The `TreeView` is using XML Binding through the `XMLDataProvider` object.

Answer (score 13):

I came across the exact same problems and wrote the following code which will work on any treeview, with just a single line call to the first function.

```
class TomWrightsUtils
{
    public static void ClearTreeViewSelection(TreeView tv)
    {
        if (tv != null)
            ClearTreeViewItemsControlSelection(tv.Items, tv.ItemContainerGenerator);
    }
    private static void ClearTreeViewItemsControlSelection(ItemCollection ic, ItemContainerGenerator icg)
    {
        if ((ic != null) && (icg != null))
            for (int i = 0; i < ic.Count; i++)
            {
                TreeViewItem tvi = icg.ContainerFromIndex(i) as TreeViewItem;
                if (tvi != null)
                {
                    ClearTreeViewItemsControlSelection(tvi.Items, tvi.ItemContainerGenerator);
                    tvi.IsSelected = false;
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Not sure what you mean by TreeNodes.

Typically you would have a corresponding `IsSelected` property on your view model that your view binds to:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
</TreeView>
```

Therefore, you would just loop through the data items in your view model and set `IsSelected = false` there.

However, it sounds like you don't have such a property. That being the case, you need to get the corresponding `TreeViewItem` for each data item. See the `TreeView.ItemContainerGenerator` property for info on how to do this. Something like:

```
var treeViewItem = _treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem;
treeViewItem.IsSelected = false;
```

Comment: I am desperately looking for a way to select first index of a TreeView.
I tried the solution from above (ContainerFromIndex) but it returns null.
Any help?

Answer (score 6):

```
TreeViewItem tvi = tvMain.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0) as TreeViewItem;

if (tvi != null) { tvi.IsSelected = true; tvi.IsSelected = false; }
```

Comment: This is the only real solution

Comment: Clear and concise should be the selected answer

Comment: It's a solution and short, but feels dirty. Unselect by selecting root and unselect it again. Still, it's probably more performant than solutions involving walking the tree.

Answer (score 2):

Find the selected item and set the value:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  TreeViewItem tvi = treeviewExample.SelectedItem as TreeViewItem;
  if (tvi != null)
  {
    tvi.IsSelected = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This works out great as a extention method so you can call

```
youTreeview.ClearSelection();

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace YourAppNamespace
{
    public static void ClearSelection(this TreeView input)
    {
    // this should be some container that you put in
    // possibly the actual treeviewitem, not sure on that though
    var selected = input.SelectedItem;
    if (selected == null)
        return;

    // in my case this works perfectly
    var tvi = input.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selected) as TreeViewItem;
    var tvi = input.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(selected) as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi == null)
    {
        // it must be a child, heres a hack fix
        // my nodes are inherited from TreeViewItemViewModel by Josh Smith
        var child = selected as WPF.Controls.TreeViewItemViewModel;
        if (child == null)
            return;
        child.IsSelected = false;

    }
    else
        tvi.IsSelected = false;
     }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's been my experience to stay away from the standard ItemContainerGenerator calls because they will fail on nodes at a depth greater than n+1.  I use the combination of the following extension methods below.  The ContainerFromItem extension methods comes from an MSDN blog and it has worked wonders for me when dealing with the TreeView.

```
  public static void ClearSelection(this TreeView input)
  {
     var selected = input.SelectedItem;

     if (selected == null) return;

     var tvi = input.ContainerFromItem(selected) as TreeViewItem;

     if (tvi == null) return;

     tvi.IsSelected = false;

  }

  public static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(this TreeView treeView, object item)
  {
     TreeViewItem containerThatMightContainItem = (TreeViewItem)treeView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
     if (containerThatMightContainItem != null)
        return containerThatMightContainItem;
     else
        return ContainerFromItem(treeView.ItemContainerGenerator, treeView.Items, item);
  }

  private static TreeViewItem ContainerFromItem(ItemContainerGenerator parentItemContainerGenerator, ItemCollection itemCollection, object item)
  {
     foreach (object curChildItem in itemCollection)
     {
        TreeViewItem parentContainer = (TreeViewItem)parentItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(curChildItem);
        if (parentContainer == null)
           return null;
        TreeViewItem containerThatMightContainItem = (TreeViewItem)parentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item);
        if (containerThatMightContainItem != null)
           return containerThatMightContainItem;
        TreeViewItem recursionResult = ContainerFromItem(parentContainer.ItemContainerGenerator, parentContainer.Items, item);
        if (recursionResult != null)
           return recursionResult;
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work so far, but I just put it in like 5 minutes ago so use at your own risk. I basically wanted to clear the selection when user clicks within the tree control, but not on a tree item.

```
 void DestinationTree_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
 {
     TreeView tree = sender as TreeView;
     DestinationClientViewModel selectedItem = tree.SelectedItem as DestinationClientViewModel;

     if (selectedItem != null)
     {
        int selectedItemIndex = this.DestinationTree.Items.IndexOf(selectedItem);

        if (selectedItemIndex > -1)
        {
            TreeViewItem tvi = this.DestinationTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(selectedItemIndex) as TreeViewItem;
            if (tvi != null)
                tvi.IsSelected = false;
        }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Ignore my code. Only works at the root level.  Any child nodes selected will not get cleared.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this situation myself with a custom Tree List View implementation after looking for a long time I finally found a solution that worked for me.

The full explanation can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36aca7f7-0b47-488b-8e16-840b86addfa3/getting-treeviewitem-for-the-selected-item-in-a-treeview

The basic idea is you capture the `TreeViewItem.Selected` event and save the source of the event into the `Tag` attribute on your TreeView. Then when you need to clear it, you can access the `Tag` attribute on your control and set the `IsSelected` value to False. This works for me with 2 levels of nested children. Hopefully it will work for you.

For persistence sake:

TreeView declaration

```
  <TreeView Name="myTreeView" TreeViewItem.Selected="OnItemSelected"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myHierarchicalData}}"/>
```

Event Handler

```
private void OnItemSelected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    myTreeView.Tag = e.OriginalSource;
}
```

Clear selection logic

```
if (myTreeView.SelectedItem != null)
{
    TreeViewItem selectedTVI = myTreeView.Tag as TreeViewItem;
    // add your code here mine was selectedTVI.IsSelected = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same problem.

A quick and dirty solution

```
tree.ItemsSource = null;

tree.ItemsSource = yourSource;
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked out perfectly for me

```
var tvi = CurvesTree.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(CurvesTree.SelectedItem) as TreeViewItem;

if (tvi is null)
    return;

tvi.IsSelected = false;
```